# Can I malloc only the exact memory needed for an input string and point it?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm making a program where I save input strings from `fgets` in a list, they have a fixed maximum lenght but can also be shorter; i save them like this:

```
typedef char line[LINE_SIZE];

struct node{
    line *t;      //pointer and not just a variable so I can "detach" the allocation to do stuff 
    struct node *prev; 
    struct node *next;
};
```

but, in my program I just do `malloc(sizeof(line))` which is an array with the maximum fixed lenght.

My question is, if I were to allocate something like `malloc( strlen( str ) + sizeof( ( char )'\0' ) )` to precisely use only the memory needed, how can I point it?

Is it okay using a `char*` inside the `node` struct? Do I risk something?

I have heard about flexible arrays inside the structs but I don't want to put the array directly inside the struct, because for the program I need to be able to detach it and then point to it with another pointer

Comment: **by definition** `sizeof ((char)'\0')` == `sizeof (char)` == `1`, so don't mess it up ... keep only `malloc(strlen(str) + 1)`

Comment: And on a POSIX platform, you can just use [`strdup()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc()` returns the address it allocated, you can assign the return value to a variable and point it. You don't need to always allocate maximum or the same size of memory even though the variable is the same member of a struct.

```
char* line=malloc(strlen(str)+1);  // +1 for null terminate
strcpy(line, "This is a str");  // points the memory of returned
```

Using a `char*` in a struct is absolutely fine. Please treat a member of struct like a plain variable.

```
struct node
{
  char* t;
  struct node* prev;
  struct node* next;
}

node n;
n.t = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);  // it's fine.
strcpy(n.t, "This is a node");  // using the memory you allocated above
n.prev = n.next = NULL;

... // doing some processing

free(n.t);  // don't forget to call free() when you're done using the memory.
```

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, you must allocate the `node` structure and the line fragment separately.

Depending on what the rest of the code assumes, you could allocate just the space for the string for each line instead of a full array, but you must change the `node` structure to use a `char *t;` instead of a `line` typedef. Note that it is very confusing to typedef arrays.

The only caveat is you must be careful when modifying these strings as you cannot add any characters at the end, nor insert any characters by moving contents beyond their allocated length. As a rule of thumb, if you reallocate these strings whenever you modify them, you should be safe.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char *t;      //pointer and not just a variable so I can "detach" the allocation to do stuff 
    struct node *prev; 
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *read_file(FILE *fp) {
    char buf[128];
    struct node *head = NULL, tail = NULL, *n = NULL;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the trailing newline if present
        n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
        if (n == NULL)
            abort();
        n->prev = tail;
        n->next = NULL;
        n->t = strdup(buf);
        if (n->t == NULL)
            abort();
        if (tail == NULL) {
            head = n;
        } else {
            tail->next = n;
        }
        tail = n;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to see me allocate the node and the line n the same call?

Comment: If you allocate the node and the line in the same block, you cannot later free the line separately, so you cannot *detach* the line and replace it with some other block because you won't know how nor when to free it.